# java -jar saxon9he.jar persons.xml persons_users.xslt -o:persons_transformed.txt

Tags: saxon

I am having an `XSLT` to convert my `xml` into `html` format. I didn't achive any Experience about Saxon before but I'll try again and again.

This is the problem I had :

> C:>java -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -t -s:samples\date\books,xml-csl:samples\styles\books,xsl -o:c:\temp.html
>
> Error: Main class net.sf.saxon.Transform could not be found or loaded

I did everything step by step from the Saxon Website :

https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/about/gettingstarted/gettingstartedjava.html

and I saw MR.Michael Kay Videos a lot before but it isn't work any way.

Can perhaps any one help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

The problems are with Java, not with Saxon, in case that helps you look in the right place for documentation.

The message "Main class net.sf.saxon.Transform could not be found or loaded" is Java telling you that it can't find Saxon.

The bit of the command that tells it where to look is this:

```
java -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform
```

Here "java" is telling the operating system to load the Java virtual machine (which has succeeded). The "-cp" option is telling Java what Jar files to search for the relevant classes, and the "net.sf.saxon.Transform" part is saying what the relevant class is.

The problem is probably that there is no file called `saxon9he.jar` in the current working directory. Unfortunately Java doesn't give you an explicit error message for this, it just ignores this part of the command. Probably the current working directory isn't what you think it is. If you do "ls" or "dir" immediately before the "java" command, it will tell you what files are in the current working directory, which should include the `saxon9he.jar` file. If the JAR file is in some other directory, you can supply an explicit path, e.g. `-cp c:/mike/java/saxon9he.jar`.